# How to count the number of rows and cols in matrix?

Tags: c

How can I count the number of rows and cols in c language after dynamic allocation?

```
void printMatrix(int **arr)
{
    int i,j;

    int col = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
    int row = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0][0]));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In my example I get only the matrix start pointer by `**arr`.

It try to run this code but it return `row = 1` and `col = 1` when the `row = 3` and `col = 2`.

Comment: `sizeof(arr) == sizeof(int**)`, it's not what you think it is.

Comment: `**arr` is a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer to a 2D array, like you seem to think.